# How do I disable a HTML element depending on its string length

Tags: php, html

i have asked this question before but all the suggested solutions did not work, so i want to rephrase it, i have an html user input field which posts data to a form  code;

```
<form method="post" action="value1.php">

    <input id="nol" style="width: 350px;" type="text" name="searchdisease" placeholder="type diagnosis one">
<input class="btn btn-success" style="width: 120px; margin-right: -90%; margin-left: 9%;" type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>
```

which is then stored in a variable and this variable is used to so select and echo results from the DB to a select tag
code;

```
<?php
 $search_disease = $_POST['searchdisease'];
                     $query="SELECT diagnosis, ICD10 FROM medications WHERE diagnosis LIKE '%$search_disease%'";
                     $result= $con->query($query);
    ?>

<select id="disease" style="width: 40%;  position: relative;top: 220px; left: 182px; " name="tdisease">
                            <option value="">Select Disease</option>
                             <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
                      <?php } ?> 
                         </select>
```

so i want to disable the above drop-down when user input is empty

like:

```
<?php
if (strlen($_POST['searchdisease'])) == 0) {
  // here i want the code to disable the select tag
      }
  ?>
```

but i have no idea which code i can use in the if statement

Comment: then go with not equal to empty condition...

Comment: please be clear about the drop down. I can find only a textbox and a button

Comment: okay i got no problem with, but how do i actually disable it?

Comment: if($search_disease!=''){ //do something;  } else { //do something; }

Comment: @JijoCleetus sorry, i forgot to add it to the question, but check updated question

Comment: @Sona its the //do something code that i want

Comment: you want to hide the select box if no input is coming means??

Comment: @Sona i mean i want to disable it

Comment: use disable word to disable the select box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Try this once...

  if($search_disease!=''){
    ?>

    <select id="disease" style="width: 40%;  position: relative;top: 220px; left: 182px; " name="tdisease">
                                <option value="">Select Disease</option>
                                 <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
                          <?php } ?> 
                             </select>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <select id="disease" style="width: 40%;  position: relative;top: 220px; left: 182px; " name="tdisease" disable>
                                <option value="">Select Disease</option>
                                 <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
                          <?php } ?> 
                             </select>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you, this does disable it, but its still there in the form, is there any way i can remove it if user input is empty? Not using the Hidden attribute

Comment: <select id="disease" style="width: 40%;  position: relative;top: 220px; left: 182px; display:none;" name="tdisease" >
                                <option value="">Select Disease</option>
                                 <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row['ICD10']?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
                          <?php } ?> 
                             </select>

Comment: thanks again, but this just hides it while its still there on the page, cant i just remove it totally?

Answer (score 0):

html set a invisible part :

```
<input type="hidden" id="aaa" value="$search_disease">
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function(){

    var i = document.getElementById("aaa").value;

    if (i==''){

        document.getElementById("disease").style.display="none";
    }
}
```